# Websphere 6.1 editor window in Eclipse/MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere, myeclipse

It was possible to double click the websphere server connector in server tab in eclipse/myeclipse to get the server editor window. But now when I do, I can not bring the editor window up. Is this feature removed or do I need to set the correct perspective. I am using MyEclipse Java perspective. Editor window allowed me to change ports and enable/disable security. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking of the Web Tools Platform (WTP) from eclipse. MyEclipse integrates much of the functionality of WTP but has a different way of configuring and deploying to servers. The MyEclipse servers view tab is called "Servers", the WTP servers view tab is called "WTP Servers". Double clicking on a server in WTP Servers will bring up an editor window of the type you describe. In the MyEclipse Servers view, you can bring up the configuration dialog by right clicking on the server and selecting "Configure Server Connector".

In base MyEclipse, you don't have the option of setting ports and security from the server connector, for WebSphere. However, if you switch to the Blue Edition of MyEclipse (more money, though), you do get more extensive configuration capability for WebSphere. I'm not sure what options you have in base MyEclipse; if you can find VM arguments (setting system properties) that provide what you want, you can set these on the JDK page of the configuration screens or, if there are program arguments that can be set, these can be added via a launch configuration, which you can create from the server connector configuration pages (and can modify them by going to the Run Configurations (which can also be reached by right clicking on the server in the Servers view).

Hope this helps. For better support, the MyEclipse forums (on their web site) are your best option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer.